# PrimeFaces component looks different than in showcase

Tags: css, primefaces

I am trying to use:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/breadcrumb.xhtml

On my site I get:

[image]

It looks like arrows are not in the middle and font is quite big and links have underline. How to change it to something similar from PrimeFaces showcase?

My theme is "bootstrap". My XHTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>  

    <h:body>
        <p:breadCrumb>
            <p:menuitem value="Categories" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Sports" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Basketball" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="NBA" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Teams" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="L.A. Lakers" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Roster" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Kobe Bryant" url="#" />
        </p:breadCrumb>
    </h:body>  
</html>
```

Comment: How is this twitter boodstrap related?

Comment: It's not ;-) Just plain CSS

Comment: @JasperdeVries: I suspected in the real version (not the code above) OP is using twitter-bootstrap css (but OP using the primefaces bootstrap them as you state in your answer might be an option to)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are using the Bootstrap theme, while the showcase is using the Omega theme by default. So first make sure you set the showcase to use the same theme you are using in your project. You can do that by clicking the "PF Themes" button (the leftmost button at the top right corner of the page when using a PC).

Then use your browser's debugging tools to inspect the breadcrumb elements (or anything on the PrimeFaces showcase). You will notice that, next to the theme's CSS, [`showcase.css`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/main/css/showcase.css.xhtml) is also loaded. One of its rules is applied on all widgets:

```
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

This is causing a difference you are also experiencing (your text is larger).

If you inspect an anchor in the breadcrumb, you will find the following rule:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #25AAE1;
}
```

Probably there are more customizations. Just have a good look at the `showcase.css`.

If you are not familiar with debugging tools, this is an example what you can expect. This screenshot was taken using Chrome. At the top you have the site. On the left hand side the DOM tree and most important in this case, at the right hand side the applied rules on the selected node. On each rule you can see from which style sheet it is loaded.

[image]

If you are interested (and using Chrome), there is great [documentation on how to use the DOM inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/) available.

Any differences you find (or at least want in your project) should be put in custom style sheet. Create a CSS file, lets say `/webapp/resources/css/custom.css`, and incorporate it in your template's head:

```
<h:head>
  ...
  <h:outputStylesheet name="css/custom.css"/>
</h:head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS in your stylesheet.

I hope this will work

CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.ui-breadcrumb ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-breadcrumb ul li a.ui-icon-home {
  margin-top: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.ui-widget-header a {
  color: #222;
}

.ui-breadcrumb ul li .ui-menuitem-link {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.ui-breadcrumb-chevron {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain why this solves this issue according to you?

Comment: I think that parent tag set different CSS values. Am i right?

Comment: @marcin Yes it renders different values. Though you can overwrite those values also by  including your custom css. For implementaion you can read short documentaion for  theme and customization  [here](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/primefaces/users-guide/more-theme-info.pdf).