# Primefaces datatable pagination on bottom screen

Tags: html, css, primefaces, xhtml

I have data table that shows my data from database. I include pagination to my data table with 'bottom' position. My code :

```
<p:dataTable var="item" id="initemList" widgetVar="initemList" value="#{initemController.initems}"
                 paginator="true" rows="50" reflow="true"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}"
                 currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords}" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50" selectionMode="single" scrollable="true"
                 selection="#{initemController.selectedInitem}" rowKey="#{item.itemid}">
```

As result, this is my data table :
[image]

My pagination is not on bottom screen, but below my data. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of styling. Use your browsers developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers) to select the node you want to style. In Chrome you can also right click the node and select "Inspect".

Now find the class you need to create a custom CSS rule. In your case: `ui-paginator-bottom`.

Then create some custom styling. Depending on your template you might end up with something like:

```
.ui-paginator-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See also:

- [PrimeFaces component looks different than in showcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358082/880619)

Comment: But for this to work you need to give the 'container' in which the '.ui-paginator' lives a fixed height, otherwise it will still be the same wouldn't it?

Comment: @Kukeltje for me this was working. But that might depend on other styling that is in place.